# How to write a structure to excel in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a structure which I want to write to excel file.

For example, I want to write A which is structure to excel. A contains both textdata and numbers which I want to write to excel.

```
>> A.textdata

ans = 

    Sheet1: {'Coco-Cola'  'CCE'}

>> A.data

ans = 

    Sheet1: [4 46.7100 46.2800 185.1200 -0.0092 -1.7200]
```

The output should be like this:
[image]

Need some guidance on how to do it.

What I have tried so far:

1) `xlswrite(filename,A);`

It gave me this error: Error using xlswrite (line 166) Input data must be a numeric, cell, or logical array.

2) `Acell = struct2cell(A);xlswrite(filename,Acell);`

It gave me this error:An error occurred on data export in CSV format. Caused by: Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Comment: I tried that xlswrite(filename,A). It gave me an error:Error using xlswrite (line 166)
Input data must be a numeric, cell, or logical array.

Comment: A is a struct and expected input of xlswrite is a numeric, cell, or logical array. Merge the data in A to a cell and then xlswrite it.

Comment: @lakesh, a question should be more than "I need some guidance". Have you thought about your problem? What did you come up with? Why didn't it work? Moreover, in your example I can't see how you can expect do generate that Excel sheet just from the information in `A` – crucial info is missing. Please revise your question.

Comment: @A.Donda I have already tried xlswrite(filename,A). It did not work for me..

Comment: @JunYoungGwak I did like you said.I converted the struct to cell using the struct2cell function. Acell = struct2cell(A); xlswrite(filename,Acell); But it gave me this error:An error occurred on data export in CSV format. Caused by:
    Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Comment: It is complaining that there are floating point number in the cell. Convert all element in the cell to string using `cellfun(@num2str, myCell, 'un', 0)`

Comment: It gives me this error now: Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in num2str (line 65)
        xmax = double(max(abs(widthCopy(:))));

Comment: @JunYoungGwak any idea?

Comment: Well, your struct is probably not a simple structure and you will have to write a code to manually go through your struct to make sure every element is converted into a cell of string.

Comment: @JunYoungGwak Not sure how to go about it. If you dun mind, can I send it to you?

Answer (score 1):

please try the following:

```
writetable(struct2table(A), 'parameters.xlsx');
```

Here, A is a structure